# Subscribe with table

Tags: angular

In my situation I have 2 questions:

1) Why my method returns 2 times the same object when I use the `console.log`

2) Why my method is not working when I add my filter. The `console.log` returns the object but I got nothing in my HTML.

In my backend everything is ok, and reduxTool shows me exactly one time each object. So I think my error is in my pipe.
If I delete the filter everything is ok but I really need this.

```
    requestList$: Observable<FriendRequest[]>;

    this.storefriends$.dispatch(new FriendsRequestFeatureStoreActions.GetFriendRequests());

    this.requestList$ = this.storefriends$.pipe(
      skipWhile(val => val === null),
      select(
        FriendsRequestFeatureStoreSelectors.selectAllFriendsRequest
      ),
      mergeMap((value: FriendRequest[]) => from(value)),
      filter((friend: any) => friend.to._id === this.user.profile),
      reduce((acc: FriendRequest[], friend: FriendRequest) => {
        console.log(friend);
        return acc.concat(friend);
      }, [])
    );
```

This is my HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let f of requestList$ | async">
    ...          
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="(requestList$| async)?.length == 0">
  not request right now...
  </div>
```

When I run in the HTML, I have nothing. Thanks if someone can help me.

Comment: Maybe because `friend.to._id === this.user.profile` return false? Provide sample data.

Comment: Thank you but I already verified this. My console.log(friends) show me exactly the data I need after the filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting multiple calls because everytime we use the `async` pipe, we create a subscription.

```
<div *ngFor="let f of requestList$ | async">
    ...          
 </div>

<div *ngIf="(requestList$| async)?.length == 0">
  not request right now...
</div>
```

To fix that you would just use the `as` keyword

```
<div *ngIf="requestList$ | async as requestList">
  <div *ngFor="let f of requestList">
    ...          
 </div>

 <div *ngIf="requestList?.length == 0">
     not request right now...
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dit the same thing but it's not working.. What is "requestList" for you ? Cause even if I add     this.requestList$.subscribe(value => {
      this.requestList = value;
    }); It still not working.. But you got reason for my multiple call thank you

Comment: `requestList` can be anything, could be `rL` or w/e, kind of like a `variable` you could say, that you can use inside your HTML Template. As for your filter issue, maybe you could use the array `filter` in your `mergeMap` instead? Another alternative that may help is create a another `selector` that does the filtering.

Comment: Thank you! Thank's to you I found the solution but I added juste take(1) after my mergeMap